# iText HtmlWorker Pre tag rendering issue

Tags: html, pdf, itext, pre

I am newbie to iText. I am trying convert html file to pdf.After conversion the contents inside the "pre tag" is not proper. If anybody come across this issue before please share your thought on this with the solution that you applied.

Comment: Are you using XmlWorker? What version are you using? What's the input? What's the output?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Document document = new Document();

    string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/");
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath + "\\pdf-"+Name+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
    FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(_webHelper.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/arial.ttf")),  "Garamond");   // just give a path of arial.ttf 
    StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "Garamond");
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
    css.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "12pt");

    hw.SetStyleSheet(css);

     hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
```

in above code see there is htmlText is a html code in string format plase pass your html viewpage code in string format and use above code, your pdf will be generate.
please note me if this code is not work.

hope this helps.